# Sidekiq Delayed Mailer does not use updated mailer views after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, unicorn, sidekiq

My production system is using Sidekiq's delayed mailer extension to send automated mails through Mailgun's smtp server.

All is well except there is a particular mail that when opened in its text alternative it uses the view from the previous deploy (while the html version is renders correctly).

Up to now I have restarted unicorn + sidekiq multiple times, I have created a new commit and deployed again while rewriting the whole view just in case but nothing works.

The production server is using unicorn, sidekiq connects to a redis instance on the same machine, while actionmailer is using the Mailgun SMTP. The mailer method is the following :

```
def new_shipment_added(shipment_id, user_id)      
  @shipment = Shipment.find(shipment_id)            
  @user = User.find(user_id)
  return false if @shipment.nil? or @user.nil?      
  rcpts = Array.new
  @user.email_addresses.each { |addrObj| rcpts << addrObj.address}
  m = mail(to: rcpts, subject: t("subject_line_with_title", title: "#{@shipment.pickup.compact_address} - #{@shipment.delivery.compact_address}"))
end
```

I am including the method for context but I think that it's not causing the problem since html templates render correctly.

The bottom line of the question is : What could be causing the problem? ..and also how is sidekiq using the older template, since it can only be found in previous releases?

Comment: Remember the sidekiq workers are running in different processes - make sure they get restarted/redeployed too.  It may seem obvious, but something is sticking around if the older templates are being used and they don't even exist on the newer deploy.